# Capitalize the first letter in the quotation in the middle of the sentence

Tags: commas, capitalization

Do I need to capitalize the first letter in the quotation in these two examples? If so, will I need to put a comma before the quotation mark?

> 1. The button produces a voice message “T/the signal is on” to tell that they are allowed.
> 2. It recognizes a person saying “T/tell me when the signal lights up."

Comment: Hi Jay this might be helpful: https://www.grammarly.com/blog/capitalization-in-quotes/

Answer (score 1):

The first letter of a directly quoted sentence has a capital letter, even if the quote is in the middle of a sentence.

> The button produces a voice message “The signal is on.” to tell that they are allowed.

(The verb "tell" normally has an object, the person who is receiving the message eg "tells the user". So that part is a little odd, but understandable.  Perhaps "indicate" instead of "tell"?)

In reported speech the capitalisation is adjusted to the sentence

> The button produces a voice message that informs the user that the signal is on when they are allowed.

Comment: But what do you do when one's own sentence includes something that is a direct quotation. Let's say my sentence was the following. *In almost all societies we discover that 'some animals are more equal than others'.* I am obliged to use quotation marks out of respect for George Orwell, but the flow of my sentence is interrupted if I use a capital S for 'Some' I am sympathetic to the OP's question, as it is a matter I still struggle with. Even though I was taught, more than 60 years ago always to begin a quotation with a capital letter.

Comment: @WS2 - but that is not what is being asked here.  The direct quote in the OPs example is a full sentence, and full sentences always start with a capital letter.  A phrase or sentence fragment is not a full sentence.

Comment: @BillyKerr I agree - and that is how I operate. But I always have this nagging thought at the back of my mind, of having been taught that all quotations should begin with a capital letter.  But clearly there are some that don't. But if I wrote *He was wondering, 'Whatever next?'* Now that's not a full sentence but it seems to me to require a capital letter.

Comment: @WS2 ... I think if you are quoting something, and the original has no capital - say a sentence fragment or a quote from the middle of a sentence, then the quote doesn't need a capital.  Direct quotes are generally verbatim - you really shouldn't change anything. If Orwell used a capital then you should, if not then you shouldn't.  It could be argued that "Whatever next?" is a full sentence BTW. - it's an expression which means "What is going to happen next?"